# Why is this $\eta$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

So in a proof I was reading, it stated that if $\eta = P(\xi\in \cdot|\mathcal{F})$, then
$\int f\, d\eta$ is $\eta$-measurable. Why is this true?

Here, $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra and $\xi$ is a random variable.

By the way, the goal is to show that $\xi$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are conditionally independent with respect to $\eta$ if that helps.

Comment: By $\eta$-measurable, do you mean $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: For that matter: $\eta$ isn't a measure: $\eta$ is a function which takes a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (presumably), say $A$, and returns the random variable $P(\xi\in A\mid\mathcal{F})$. What does it mean to integrate against such a function?

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I believe it is both, though I am equally unsure what the question is asking. Comment too long, so I posted an answer. Thoughts?

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson By definition, $\int fd\eta=E(f(\xi)\mid\mathcal F)$ (but this remark does not explain the meaning of "$\eta$-measurable" here).

Comment: OP: How do you define conditional independence (of two sigma-algebras, say) conditionally on a random measure?

Comment: To be honest, that's what I was confused about as well. This was a problem from my Kallenberg textbook I'm reading and I spent a long time trying to interpret that too.

Answer (score 0):

Let us interpret the event for the case where $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma-algebra generated by a partition $P = {A_1,\dots,A_n}$, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$, and $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i = \Omega$, just to get some intuition. We set $\mathcal{F} := \sigma(P)$. The conditional expectation then takes the simple form:
$$E[X | \mathcal{F}] = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{E[X I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)}I_{A_i}(\omega).$$
We define $P(X \in B| \mathcal{F}) := E[1_B(X) | \mathcal{F}]$. For each measurable $B$ in the state space, the mapping $\omega\rightarrow P(X \in B | \mathcal{F})(\omega)$ is a measurable random variable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$, and for each fixed $\omega$, $B \rightarrow P(X \in B | \mathcal{F})(\omega)$ is a measure. Thus,
$$\eta(B) := P(X \in B | \mathcal{F})$$
defines a true measure, for each fixed $\omega$. This is known as a regular conditional probability.

Now, what you are asking is a little unclear. Since this family of probability measures (one for each $\omega$ a.s.) is 'dependent' on $\xi$, you might expect that $\int f d\eta$ is $\xi$-measurable, but you might have to provide information on how $f$ is defined (if $\eta$ is a probability measure, presumably $\int_S f d\eta$ is a number? $S$ is the state space.)